# How to render adaptive cards in Xamarin.Forms Project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, adaptive-cards

How can I implement Adaptive Card Renderer in Xamarin.Forms for both Android & IOS? Any nuget packages available?

Comment: What is an adaptive card renderer can you show me an image of this?

Comment: @G.hakim Adaptive Cards is the name of an Microsoft data (json-based) exchange  specification (used mainly in bots, but not limited to that of course), they have platform specific "data renderers" for HTML, Android, iOS, UWP, WPF, etc...  https://adaptivecards.io /  https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards

Comment: Adaptive cards from chat bot. You can check out this link https://adaptivecards.io/ to have better image on it.

Comment: @SushiHangover I see thanks a lot.

Comment: I have checked out on this sample project http://monsoon.cloud/2018/03/11/xamarin-chatbots/
However they are using Xamarin Forms Renderer that are still in alpha stage which I can't find in nuget

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/Clancey/BotFramework ?

Comment: I think this requires using CustomRenderer to use Adaptive Cards.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/android/render-a-card)(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/ios/render-a-card#render-a-card)@Lily.T

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT do u mind sharing how to invoke the *Render Card* method in both IOS and Android platforms in the Xamarin.Forms project?

Comment: @Lily.T Sorry I not used Render Card before , it needs more time to know it.If I have a sample, I will share here :)